# Images not compressing on IIS 8.5 with Cloudflare

Tags: asp.net, iis, cloudflare, http-compression

I've got a web app on IIS 8.5 running on Windows Server 2012 R2 which is running through CloudFlare.  Js,html and css files are compressing perfectly using gzip but I cannot get the images to compress.

[http://www.allaboutstalbans.com/home](http://www.allaboutstalbans.com/)

I've got static and dynamic compression enabled and have tried various web.config httpCompression tweaks to get it to work but without success.

Has anyone come across this before?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually seeing some images being gzipped. Do you have the correct content type/encoding specified for all images?